# How to add the BgImage on UIButton or UIBarButtonItem using Interface Builder?

Tags: c#, iphone, user-interface, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

How to add the BGImage on MonoTouch UI components?  Anyone know how do we set the image for a UI components not programmatically? this is, using the interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reference the image from interface builder.   Although it wont show up, the image will be recorded in the XIB file.

Then make sure that you add those files to your project and they are marked as Content.